# greek-babel sticks compiler

Tags: babel, greek

I have researched various answers but I can't seem to be able to answer mine. I am trying to compile greek for the first time in LaTeX and therefore tried to experiment with this very simple code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
\usepackage[iso-8859-7]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
    \textgreek{Γειά!}
\end{document}
```

When I press compile, the compiler simply nevers returns. It just compiles forever. When I remove the command:

```
\textgreek
```

and place my text in the code plainly, I am getting errors about letters (i.e. \textGamma or \textepsilon) unavailable in encoding OT1.

I am using TexStudio as editor with MiKTeX.

Comment: Are you sure your document is saved in iso-8859-7 encoding? Perhaps `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` can solve the issue.

Comment: Unfortunatelly the problem persists, compiler never returns.

Comment: You mean, after changing `inputenc` to `utf8`? You sure you have the Greek fonts installed? BTW, `amsmath` may not be required for the MWE.

Comment: MiKTeX isn't a LaTeX package. Do you mean that you have a basic installation of TeX installed using the MiKTeX package manager? I don't use MiKTeX, so I don't know if this makes sense or not. If you remove the Greek and put 'Hello World!' instead, does the document compile then?

Comment: @cfr This was very enlightening! This is what I ment, I did't realise MiKTex is a package manager and yes the document compiles normally.

Comment: Put the Greek back and post the log file.